# Get notified only when a list/card being archived

Tags: trello

We are having many cards everyday; instead of subscribing the whole board (and getting too many nofitication), is it possible to get notified only when list/card being archived?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a feature to subscribe to archiving, but an alternative is to create an 'archive' list, move the 'done' cards to that list and subscribe to the 'archive' list.

Answer (score 0):

If this then that might help?

https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=trello&ac=false